# Why am I running into an error when trying to apply a minimumModuleVersionOverride?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

We need to specify jobSpecOverrides in transforms-python/build.gradle in order to specify spark module of previous version to use:

```
jobSpecOverrides {
    minimumModuleVersionOverride {
        version = "1.579.0"
        expiresAfter = "2022-12-30T08:00Z"
    }
}
```

We always get an error like:

```
> Could not find method jobSpecOverrides() for arguments [build_7fuwjnfbdqnzske0gypcnsj4u$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure4$_closure7@52c272c2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.
```

How can we avoid getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks mostly correct, you just need to be sure that the minimum module version is all the way at the bottom of the `build.gradle` file.

Example:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username ''
                password transformsBearerToken
            }
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            url project.transformsMavenProxyRepoUri
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.palantir.transforms.python:lang-python-gradle-plugin:${transformsLangPythonPluginVersion}"
    }
}


jobSpecOverrides {
    minimumModuleVersionOverride {
        version = "1.376.0" // there must be a version that's runnable on the stack that's greater than or equal to this. also must be higher than the transforms-defined one.
        expiresAfter = "2021-11-09T08:00Z" // must be at most 7 days after the time CI runs.
    }
}
```